# rsync: need help resolving a "nomenclature" question

Tags: rsync, documentation

I've used `rsync` for a while, and it's always performed very well. However, trying to `rsync` my macOS (source, APFS file system) with my Synology NAS (dest, btrfs filesystem) seems to always present "challenges" that I don't find in other uses of `rsync`.

Some of my "challenges" are with the [*nomenclature*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nomenclature) used in (particularly) the `rsync` documentation; i.e. `man rsync`. I'm hoping to find some clarification with this question; following are the specifics:

###### `rsync` is "one-way" synchronization; `man rsync` describes the `-i` (`--itemize-changes`) as follows:

```
[output is cryptic string] that is 11 letters long. The general format is    
YXcstpoguax, where Y is replaced by the type of update being done ... 

A < means that a file is being transferred to the remote host (sent)  

A > means that a file is being transferred to the local host (received)
```

When using the following `rsync` command:

```
# Version:
rsync --version
rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31   

# The command (simplified)
rsync -rlAtgoDiv /Users/seamus/Desktop/ /Volumes/backups/Desktop
```

I get the following output:

```
>f..t....... BooksBlogsEtc/pix/Capucine02.jpg
```

This is where I lose the plot. The `>` says `"file being transferred to local host (received)"`, but taking this statement at [*face value*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-at-face-value), it says that the file is being transferred **to** my Mac and **from** the NAS - it is being **received**. IOW, I have [*conflated*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflate) the term `source` with `sent` and (to a lesser degree) `local host`. But this is not what seems to be going on - the file in the example above is being sent **from** the source/Mac **to** the dest/NAS.

Can someone explain these *apparent* discrepancies to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rsync runs in *three* different modes.

- Copy from remote to local (pull)
- Copy from local to remote (push)
- Copy from local to local (local)

"sent" and "received" have an unambiguous meaning in the first two cases, not so much in the third.

When you use a local to local copy, it will always show the `>` symbol for transfers.

While your `/Volumes/backup/Desktop` may be backed by a NAS, `rsync` doesn't know that.   It's not using any of the remote protocols that define a remote side (remote shell or rsync daemon).   As far as the program is concerned, these are just local filesystems.   The network portion isn't being done by `rsync`, it's being done by your OS.  As such, it will always show `>`.

If your NAS had an rsync daemon and you chose to connect to it via something like:

`rsync -rlAtgoDiv /Users/seamus/Desktop/ user@nas.local:/backup/Desktop`

then `rsync` would treat the destination as a remote device and it would show the transfer with a `<` character.

Comment: Very good! I'll postpone acceptance for a day or two just in case I get a better answer - but I doubt that's gonna' happen. I was not aware of the 3 modes, but this makes sense... if you've got a reference to support your concluding stmt (`"sent" and "received" have an unambiguous meaning in the first two cases, not so much in the third.`) I'd love to see that.

Comment: That's just my opinion! :-).   But it makes sense that if only one side is local, you should look at it from that (local) point of view.   remote->local, you are receiving.   local->remote, you are sending.

Comment: Consider the third option to be `cp` and you won't be far wrong

Comment: I've done some testing today w/ the `rsync daemon` on the Synology NAS, and I've convinced myself that your "opinion" is correct. Thanks again for a prompt and excellent answer.